# How can I create guide lines around an object automatically in adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, guides

I'm wondering if there is a way to create guide lines around an object automatically with any kind of command in illustrator. Because I remmenber that I did it once accidentally but I don't know the real command. I just want to be more efficient and quick.

This is the result I would like to get:

-From this:

[image: example text without guidelines]
-To this:
[image: example text with guidelines around it]

Thanks!! :D

Comment: You mean all guides at the same time? As in you press a button and the object is surrounded by guides? Or are you just trying to 'snap' guides to the edges of the object?

Comment: Yeah I mean that, all at the same time, to get the object surrounded by guides.

Comment: are you sure you didn't have a plugin or script to do this? I personally can't recall such command in Illustrator

Comment: I think I did it once, and if I remmenber correctly I did it with no plugins, and I think Illustrator should have no problem doing that since it is able to create crop lines to cut it out easier.

Comment: What is automatic in Illustrator is to fit the artboard to a selected object, but no the guides.

Comment: yeah I know, but if that is possible, how is not possible the guide line thing? :S

Comment: ad rip that's just not how illustrator works

Answer (score 2):

With the rectangle selected, make an action:

- **Menu View** > **Guides** > **Make Guides**
- **Copy**
- Checking the **Center Reference Point** of transformation, define the height to 3000 px
- **Menu Edit** > **Past in Front**
- Define the width to 3000 px

[image: action]